# How do i revert/stop a transaction mid way in PayPal javascript sdk

Tags: angular, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am new in Angular and i am trying to integrate paypal as a payment gateway. I dont undertsand what flow to follow

```
  paypal
  .Buttons({
    createOrder: (data, actions) => {
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [
          {
            description: this.data.description,
            amount: {
              currency_code: 'EUR',
              value: 200
            }
          }
        ]
      });
    },
    onApprove: async (data, actions) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.bookPackage(data);

    },
    onError: err => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  })
  .render(this.paypalElement.nativeElement);
```

I am assuming that i call the payment gateway to do the transaction and if it succeeds i make the call to my server to book the package in the onApprove callback. But what do i do if my BookPackage api call fails. How can i undo the transaction?

Answer (score 0):

After approval (in onApprove) You need to capture, or at least authorize, the PayPal order.

The capture (or authorize) is more likely to fail than your bookPackage backend call (e.g. if the credit card is declined), so you should do the PayPal capture/authorize first.  Then do your bookPackage.  Finally if you did an authorization, you do need to capture in the end as a third API call.

[If you need to "undo" the transaction due to a failed bookPackage, refund the capture, or if you only authorized, void the authorization.]

---

For best results you should be using a server-side integration, and performing all operations from the server end.

Here is the front-end code to use: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

You will need at least two routes, 'Set Up Transaction' (with intent:capture or authorize), and a second one for 'Capture Transaction' https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

(or of course authorize instead, if you're going that more complicated multi-step route)